# file_put_contents on PHP won't work due to permission denial on www-data user

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2

I'm very new to linux and I wanted to run a certain php test file on amazon linux VM image for the first time, but due to permission error, I cannot proceed running my test tool.

Here's our installer.php code to check if we have write permission. All files are stored in /var/www/html/ folder.

```
if(file_put_contents("check.txt", " ")===FALSE) {
            echo json_encode(array("error"=>1, "message"=>"Provide WRITE permission to www-data."));
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            unlink("check.txt");
        }
```

And here's our /var/www/ permission:

```
[ec2-user@ip-1xx-xx-2x-xx www]$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwsr-x+  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 19 00:12 cgi-bin
drwxrwsr-x+  3 www-data www-data 4096 Dec  2 10:41 error
drwxrwsr-x+ 11 www-data www-data 4096 Dec  3 12:34 html
drwxrwsr-x+  3 www-data www-data 4096 Dec  2 11:08 icons
```

/var/www/html/ permission:

```
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data    3942 Oct 12 12:40 action.php
drwxrwsr-x+ 5 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 29 19:44 backend
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data     212 Dec  2 17:11 countdown.js
drwxrwsr-x+ 3 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 29 19:44 css
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 29 19:44 img
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data      42 Oct  5 22:26 index.php
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 13 04:22 install
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data    2087 Dec  2 22:26 installer.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data    4890 Dec  2 18:26 install.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data    6499 Oct 13 04:15 settings.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data    3753 Oct 12 04:02 tables.sql
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data   19965 Oct 20 02:20 inventory.php
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 29 19:44 js
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data      41 Dec  3 12:32 key.txt
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data    8643 Oct 12 12:40 keywords.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data  181043 Sep 29 14:15 loader-wizard.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data    4174 Oct 26 00:10 login.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data     480 Oct 12 12:40 logout.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data      47 Oct 13 03:55 runTime.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 www-data www-data   44391 Sep 29 14:15 loader-wizard.zip
```

Comment: Try to get full path of saved file. May be work dir of httpd process is not equal /var/www/html.

Comment: I mean try to use full path in file_put_contents("/var/www/html/check.txt", " ")